# 'Most popular' view

Tags: 6, views, nodes

I created a view which is supposed to list the 5 most popular stories on my site, so I sorted by node statistics: total views, and included several content types in filters. Only problem is the view only checks the stories in the first content type selected and ignores all the others. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is an export of the view:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'popular';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'created' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'date_format' => 'small',
    'custom_date_format' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'created',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'created',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'label' => '',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'totalcount' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'id' => 'totalcount',
    'table' => 'node_counter',
    'field' => 'totalcount',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'news' => 'news',
      'story' => 'story',
      'opinion' => 'opinion',
      'video' => 'video',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => 'type_op',
      'label' => 'Node: Type',
      'use_operator' => 0,
      'identifier' => 'type',
      'optional' => 1,
      'single' => 1,
      'remember' => 0,
      'reduce' => 0,
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 5);
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('block_description', '');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Comment: Did you check multiple content types on your filter or add a filter for each content type?

Comment: I checked multiple content types...

Comment: Are you sure it's not checking the other content types? Perhaps your top 5 happen to be that first content type. Sorry guessing here, but not much to work with

Comment: That's also what I thought, so I just unchecked the first content type and left the others, and it displayed stories from the following content type only.

Comment: So after removing that first content type it still showed that type in the view?

Comment: No after removing the first content type it only showed nodes from the second content type (which then effectively became the first content type) and ignored all the others.

Comment: @Jane let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/795/discussion-between-laxman13-and-jane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that Content view counting is enabled in the Access Log Settings (`admin/reports/settings`).  If this isn't enabled all content views will be equal to `0`.

[image: Count content views]

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider the radioactivity module [Radioactivity module](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) which gives a more accurate and relevant reflection on the current popular content on the site.

The problem with using total views is that over time, the oldest content will always appear at the top of the list as they've been around longer. Whereas with the radioactivity module, it uses a points system and radioactivity "halflife" to rank content. This way, it will give a true reflection of the current trends of your site.

There's a handy video [here](http://www.vimeo.com/9337149) which explains it all.

Hope this helps!